# how to change SQLserver 2k8 R2 user password

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i need to change `SA` user password in SQL-server-2k8-R2 version and how to create new user in same version....

```
please describe me steps. how to i achieve this....
```

Thanks to advance....

Answer (score 0):

[Refer img1](http://sql-password-recovery.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/change-SQL-server-password.gif)

Select the user name and its properties and you will find it.

[refer img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUxJd.png)